# is there a good react carousel components that will work with gatsby-image?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm trying to make a carousel to display some images of projects I've done. I know there are a lot of react carousel components around, so does anyone know of one that will work well with gatsby-image?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use [`react-slick`](https://react-slick.neostack.com/) that is very good and I can make it work with Gatsby Image.

Example in a page :

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

import Slider from "react-slick"
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css"

const settings = {
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
}

const CarouselPage = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Slider {...settings} className="overflow-hidden">
      <Img fluid={data.image1.childImageSharp.fluid} />
      <Img fluid={data.image2.childImageSharp.fluid} />
    </Slider>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    image1: file(relativePath: { eq: "my-image-1-path.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    image2: file(relativePath: { eq: "my-image-2-path.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default CarouselPage
```